# Using regular expressions to match a variable length string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match a variable length string, remove certain text. Here are some examples of trying to achieve:

```
Equipment Changes: 2 - Mon Rose - Blinkers On;7 - Queen's Harbor - Blinkers On
```

### Would yield

```
2 - Mon Rose - Blinkers On;7 - Queen's Harbor - Blinkers On
```

The example above includes 2 equipment changes, however, there could be 1 to 12 equipment changes. I'm hoping that one regular expression can handle all circumstances. The horse names will always vary as will the type of equipment changes (Blinkers On, Blinkers Off, Bar Shoe, etc)

I can match one, but I'm having difficulty with the variable requirement.

My code for matching one equipment change follows:

```
(Equipment Changes:)\s[\dA-Z]{1,2}\s-\s[A-Za-z\d]{1,18}\s-\s[A-Z]\s?[a-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+\s?[A-Za-z]
```

This matches one equipment change.I was hoping to be able to + or {1,12} to make it handle multiple changes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to have a set of many entries and other set with the corresponding desired outputs. It would be nice if you put your current code and the results of applying it to the same entry set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not trying to separate the equipment changes, this should work. (Passes everything until the colon then takes the rest of the string.)

```
    .*:(.*\z)
```

And if you are trying to separate them you can split using the semicolon. (Passes everything until the colon then takes pieces of the string separated by semicolon and the last piece ends when the string ends.)

```
    .*:(.*;)*(.*)\z
```

Comment: Wow that's efficient. I just tried it out in Rublar and it worked like a charm.  One question. What is it about the first solution that eliminates the Equipment Change text.   Thanks.

Comment: The period is for any character or whitespace and the asterisk allows it to repeat as many times as it can before it reaches the semicolon. The stuff inside the parentheses is what's captured.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did realize the parenthesis could be used to exclude. Thanks again!